# Run-time error '1004: Method 'Color' of object 'Interior' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am encountering a "Run-time error '1004: Method 'Color' of object 'Interior' failed" error when I include the code,

```
 Worksheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly := True
```

within my code.

My goal is to protect certain cells within my worksheet, while allowing users to modify other cells essential for data input.  I am relatively new to VBA coding.  Any insight a more experienced programmer might provide would be very, very appreciated.

The code I am using is pasted below. The first line on which I receive the 1004 error is:

```
Asheet.Range("a4").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255)
```

Thank you very much!

**My Code:**

```
Sub BowelHelathMacro()

    'Declaring Variables

    Dim Asheet As Worksheet
    Dim Dsheet As Worksheet

    Set Asheet = Sheets("Analysis")
    Set Dsheet = Sheets("Data")


    'Locking Cells/Spreadsheet(s)

    'Unprotect Cells:

        Dsheet.Range("c3:e13").locked = False
        Dsheet.Range("c3:e13").FormulaHidden = False

        Asheet.Range("g5:h15").locked = False
        Asheet.Range("g5:h15").FormulaHidden = False

'    'Protect Sheets:

        Dsheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

        Asheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True



'Clear Previous Day's Spreadsheet

    Asheet.Range("a1:o15").Clear


'Insert Headers
'**CONSIDER ADDING "thisworkbook.sheets..." in order to prevent overwriting

    Asheet.Range("a4") = "Date"
    Asheet.Range("b4") = "Caution?"
    Asheet.Range("c4") = "Last"
    Asheet.Range("d4") = "First"
    Asheet.Range("e4") = "Last Bowel Movement"
    Asheet.Range("f4") = "Prune Juice Administered Last Night?"
    Asheet.Range("g4") = "Action Steps"
    Asheet.Range("h4") = "Comments"

    Asheet.Select

    Asheet.Range("a4:h4").Select
        Selection.Font.Bold = True

'Color Interior of Analysis Headers

    Asheet.Range("a4").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255)
    Asheet.Range("b4").Interior.Color = RGB(300, 75, 75)
    Asheet.Range("c4").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255)
    Asheet.Range("d4").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255)
    Asheet.Range("e4").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 100)
    Asheet.Range("f4").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 100)
    Asheet.Range("g4").Interior.Color = RGB(300, 75, 75)
    Asheet.Range("h4").Interior.Color = RGB(204, 204, 255)


'Insert Key for Colors: Orange & Blue

    Asheet.Range("a1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
    Asheet.Range("a2").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)

    Asheet.Range("b1") = "Caution: Potential Bowel Health Complications"
    Asheet.Range("b2") = "Bowel Movement within Healthy Parameters"

    Asheet.Range("a1:a2").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With

'Insert Updated Date Range (2 weeks back) into Data Tab

    Dsheet.Select
        Range("i3") = Date - 14
        Range("i4") = Date - 13
        Range("i5") = Date - 12
        Range("i6") = Date - 11
        Range("i7") = Date - 10
        Range("i8") = Date - 9
        Range("i9") = Date - 8
        Range("i10") = Date - 7
        Range("i11") = Date - 6
        Range("i12") = Date - 5
        Range("i13") = Date - 4
        Range("i14") = Date - 3
        Range("i15") = Date - 2
        Range("i16") = Date - 1
        Range("i17") = Date

'Copy & Paste Current Individual Names from "Data" Tab

Dsheet.Select
    Range("A3:B13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Asheet.Select
    Range("c5").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

'Insert Today's Date

    For x = 5 To 15

        Cells(x, 1) = Date

    Next x

'ANALYSIS: (1) Caution or Non-Caution Analysis; (2) Last Bowel Movement Analysis

    'Individual Position 01

        If Dsheet.Range("c3") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b5").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e5") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m3") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c3") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b5").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e5") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m3") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 02

        If Dsheet.Range("c4") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e6") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m4") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c4") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b6").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e6") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m4") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 03

        If Dsheet.Range("c5") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b7").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e7") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m5") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c5") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b7").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e7") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m5") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 04

        If Dsheet.Range("c6") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e8") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m6") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c6") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b8").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e8") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m6") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 05

        If Dsheet.Range("c7") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b9").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e9") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m7") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c7") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b9").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e9") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m7") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 06

        If Dsheet.Range("c8") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b10").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e10") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m8") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c8") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b10").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e10") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m8") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 07

        If Dsheet.Range("c9") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b11").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e11") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m9") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c9") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b11").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e11") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m9") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 08

        If Dsheet.Range("c10") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b12").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e12") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m10") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c10") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b12").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e12") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m10") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 09

        If Dsheet.Range("c11") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e13") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m11") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c11") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b13").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e13") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m11") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 10

        If Dsheet.Range("c12") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b14").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e14") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m12") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c12") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b14").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e14") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m12") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If

    'Individual Position 11

        If Dsheet.Range("c13") < Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b15").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Asheet.Range("e15") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m13") & ", MORE than two days ago."

        End If

        If Dsheet.Range("c13") >= Dsheet.Range("i15") Then

            Asheet.Range("b15").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255)
            Asheet.Range("e15") = "Last bowel movement on " & Dsheet.Range("m13") & "." & " Within healthy tolerance levels."

        End If


'ANALYSIS: Prune Juice Administration

    'Individual 01

        Asheet.Range("f5") = Dsheet.Range("e3") & "."

    'Individual 02

        Asheet.Range("f6") = Dsheet.Range("e4") & "."

    'Individual 03

        Asheet.Range("f7") = Dsheet.Range("e5") & "."

    'Individual 04

        Asheet.Range("f8") = Dsheet.Range("e6") & "."

    'Individual 05

        Asheet.Range("f9") = Dsheet.Range("e7") & "."

    'Individual 06

        Asheet.Range("f10") = Dsheet.Range("e8") & "."

    'Individual 07

        Asheet.Range("f11") = Dsheet.Range("e9") & "."

    'Individual 08

        Asheet.Range("f12") = Dsheet.Range("e10") & "."

     'Individual 08

        Asheet.Range("f13") = Dsheet.Range("e11") & "."

    'Individual 09

        Asheet.Range("f14") = Dsheet.Range("e12") & "."

    'Individual 10

        Asheet.Range("f15") = Dsheet.Range("e13") & "."

     'Individual 11

        Asheet.Range("f16") = Dsheet.Range("e14") & "."

'ANALYSIS: Action Steps

    'Individual 01

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b5").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g5") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g5").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b5").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e3") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g5") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b5").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e3") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g5") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

    'Individual 02

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g6") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g6").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b6").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e4") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g6") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b6").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e4") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g6") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

    'Individual 03

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b7").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g7") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g7").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b7").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e5") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g7") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b7").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e5") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g7") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

    'Individual 04

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g8") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g8").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b8").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e6") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g8") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b8").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e6") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g8") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

    'Individual 05

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b9").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g9") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g9").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b9").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e7") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g9") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b9").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e7") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g9") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

    'Individual 06

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b10").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g10") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g10").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b10").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e8") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g10") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b10").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e8") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g10") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

    'Individual 07

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b11").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g11") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g11").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b11").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e9") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g11") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b11").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e9") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g11") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

    'Individual 08

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b12").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g12") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g12").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b12").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e10") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g12") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b12").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e10") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g12") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

    'Individual 09

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g13") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g13").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b13").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e11") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g13") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b13").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e11") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g13") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

     'Individual 10

        'If Orange:

            If Asheet.Range("b14").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

                Asheet.Range("g14") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
                Asheet.Range("g14").Select
                    Selection.Font.Bold = True

            End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

            If Asheet.Range("b14").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e12") = "Yes" Then

                Asheet.Range("g14") = "None."

            End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

            If Asheet.Range("b14").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e12") = "No" Then

                Asheet.Range("g14") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

            End If

    'Individual 11

        'If Orange:

        If Asheet.Range("b15").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0) Then

            Asheet.Range("g15") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
            Asheet.Range("g15").Select
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "Yes":

        If Asheet.Range("b15").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e13") = "Yes" Then

            Asheet.Range("g15") = "None."

        End If

        'If Blue & PJ = "No":

        If Asheet.Range("b15").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 255) And Dsheet.Range("e13") = "No" Then

            Asheet.Range("g15") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."

        End If

'Data Validation for "Action Steps" Column

    'Input Data Validation Criteria

        Asheet.Range("o4") = "Action Steps Data Validation"
        Asheet.Range("o5") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Managment that prune juice has not been administered."
        Asheet.Range("o6") = "None."
        Asheet.Range("o7") = "Notify RN, LPN, & Management of POTENTIAL HEALTH HAZARD!"
        Asheet.Range("o8") = "See Comments Column."

    'Data Validation

        Range("g5:g15").Select
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="=$O$5:$O$8"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With

'Applying Borders to "Analysis" Tab

    Asheet.Range("A4:h15").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With

'Format Range e:5,h:15 as Wrapped Text

    Asheet.Range("E4:h15").Select
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .wraptext = True
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .MergeCells = False
        End With


End Sub
```

Comment: unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm not getting an error either, what if you move the protection to the end of the macro?  or try copying it into a new workbook with the right sheets.

Comment: Is the worksheet not protected before you ran this macro?